# Accepted answer is not an answer to the question, because apparently the question was bad

Tags: discussion, questions, bad-questions

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35981362/if-something-can-convert-to-string-in-c-sharp/35981628#35981628)

Should I update the question, so it fits the answer OP gave, or should I flag the answer as not an answer?

He wasn't able to explain his problem even in direct questions in comments, and then gives an answer that doesn't solve his question (directly). So future visitors will be confused.

What is the "goto" for this kind of error?

I think this isn't a duplicate here on meta, since the guy who asked the question also answered it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should I update the question, so it fits the answer OP gave

No, you should not change a question based on an answer.

> should I flag the answer as not an answer?

Yes. Answers that don't attempt to answer the question should be flagged as NAA.

Comment: Alright, I'll do that.

Answer (score 2):

In general I think it is OK to amend a question in the light of an accepted answer. I've done this occasionally. Altering the title to describe the important part of the problem is especially useful.

However, such amendment means the question was unclear. If the question was very poor, such improvements are not worthwhile. So you should always consider a down vote and a vote to close as unclear what you are asking instead of this editing.

Comment: Okay, I guess the question was just that poor. The problem is, that there is an solution to the question, but its not what OP wanted, so thats why the answer with the green check is wrong.

Comment: ok so now the "wrong" answer from OP has been deleted. I guess its a question that is ok to learn from now.